# For which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\frac{1}{1+\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert^{\alpha}}$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\lvert\lvert \,.\rvert\rvert$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\frac{1}{1+\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert^{\alpha}}$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$?

---

My approach: I have tried to approximate $\frac{1}{1+\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert^{\alpha}}$ from below using simple functions but nothing useful has presented itself. Is there a better way for solving this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere Go to the spherical coordinates section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change to polar coordinates, you will see it all comes down to

$$\int_0^\infty {r^{n-1}\, dr\over 1 + r^\alpha}.$$

The integrand is continuous, so you only need to analyze what makes it integrate at $\infty$.